# Creating a Javascript/JQuery HTML Table Heatmap with percent and non-numeric values

Tags: javascript, jquery, heatmap

I am pretty new to javascript and I'm trying to use jquery-colorize to heatmap a html table. The code for the main js function is at https://github.com/gryevns/jquery-colorize/blob/master/jquery-colorize.js

I'm calling this function in my template using

```
$("table tbody td").colorize({});
```

The problem is that my actual table has percents and some string values. Right now, I can only get this function to work with numerical values in the table.

How can I modify this script so that I can:

1) Completely Ignore any non-numeric values in the  tags without breaking the function

2) Convert percents to float values in the table (I've tried doing this via

```
this.slice(0, this.length-1)
```

to drop the percent character at the end but its still not working.

I've created a jsfiddle for it: jsfiddle.net/k3rud9ck/

I'm pretty new to JS so any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you need to do is modify line 9 on the plugin:

```
return parseFloat(e.html());
```

You could perhaps change it to

```
return parseFloat(e.html()) | 0;
```

This will set the cells value to 0 if it's not numeric. Percents are already converted to floats properly, since `parseFloat` will ignore the `%`